# Absolute sturctured reference in Excel 2007/2010

Tags: excel, reference

I'm trying to created an "absolute structered reference" in Excel 2007.  Formula example is as follows:

```
=PRODUCT(VLOOKUP([Pilot Name], Loot, MATCH(Table4[[#Headers],[Arkonor]], Loot[#Headers], 0), FALSE), 1)
```

Where `[Pilot Name]` is the first column of the table, `[Arkonor]` is the second column.  What I want to be able to do is have `[Pilot Name]` remain static while `[Arkonor]` agrees with the header at the top of the current column as I fill across the table.

Currently, when I fill across the table, I get:

```
=PRODUCT(VLOOKUP([Arkonor], Loot, MATCH(Table4[[#Headers],[Bistot]], Loot[#Headers], 0), FALSE), 1)
```

But I would like to have:

```
=PRODUCT(VLOOKUP([Pilot Name], Loot, MATCH(Table4[[#Headers],[Bistot]], Loot[#Headers], 0), FALSE), 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

consider your Pilot is in column `A1`,

you need mark it as `$A$1`, this makes the field static & will not be changed as the formula is filled across the table.

Comment: Is there no way to do this in a structured setting rather than a cell reference setting?

Comment: you can create a structured setting variable in excel just create a name variable referring a cell (A1). then use the name in the next sheet.